# Active in Navigation

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2

I have login/registration module. In navigation, I have Login and Register. I want to make Login active when I press Login, and Register active when I press Register.

My layout.phtml is:

```php
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
    <li class="active">
      <a href="<?php echo $this->url('users/login') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Login') ?></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $this->url('users/register') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Register') ?></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here Login is active.

Comment: You might want to add some more information about how you have structured your application, and what you have tried so far. Did you have a look at `Zend\Navigation` already?

Comment: I have changed the indentation of your php code to make it more readable on the screen. Remember, on Stack Overflow you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear and useful as possible.